# Outlook doesn't send answer to event invitation via iCal

Tags: outlook, gmail, icalendar, data-synchronization, zimbra

I am trying to send an invitation to an event in form of an iCal email attachment. I'm testing it with 3 clients: Zimbra, Gmail and Outlook. All three interpret the attachment correctly: They show the respective RSVP buttons (Accept/Tentative/Decline). However, after pressing the button, only Zimbra sends an email with an iCal file containing the answer. Gmail and Outlook don't.

Is this a normal behavior, or am I doing something wrong? I would expect the clients to send an email with an answer. Saving the data only to a local calendar doesn't make much sense to me.

Example of the iCal I am sending:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//Calendar APP
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180424T084322Z
DTSTART:20180424T000000
DTEND:20180424T235959
SUMMARY:e107
TZID:Europe/Vienna
LOCATION:Besprechungsraum 1
SEQUENCE:0
ORGANIZER:mailto:organizer@mail.com
UID:20180424T084322Z-confId=795:timeTableId=18997@fe80:0:0:0:e73:2050:cc3
 d:6035%utun0
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=;PARTSTAT=NEEDS_ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:
 user@mail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=;PARTSTAT=NEEDS_ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:
 another_user@mail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to specify in your question how many calendaring systems are involved between organiser and attendees. For example, if both organiser and attendee are on gmail, iMIP is most likely not involved. For Outlook, is the calendar synchronised with a server side calendar or is is a purely local calendar ?

Comment: The goal is to synchronize local clients (Outlook, Exchange & Gmail) with my server. I was expecting that all the clients send a synchronization email when the attendee accepts. This is how Zimbra behaves, for example. My question is: Is it a beahavior specific for Zimbra, or Outlook or Gmail do it as well, but I haven't set something correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you're still looking for an answer on this but I do know (from learning the hard way) that if you send your test message from a gmail account but are answering on behalf of a DIFFERENT gmail account, then gmail will not send back a response. So if you're using testacct1@gmail to send a recipient (testacct2@gmail) on behalf of a THIRD acct (testacct3@gmail) gmail will not send the reply. Google checks the sender against the invitee. If they don't match, you will not get a response.